# retrieve value of a input with type="number"

Tags: php

My HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="post">
            <lable>Name</lable>
            <input name="name" type="text">
            <lable>Phone</lable>
            <input name"phone" type="number">
            <lable>Email</lable>
            <input name"email" type="email">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
    echo "Welcome dear $name to our website, <br>";
    echo "Your phone number is $phone and your email ID is $email";
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Veeraj · Lecture 36
· 2 hours ago

Output is

Welcome dear Keerthi to our website
Your phone number is and your email ID is

I am not being able to retrieve values in the filed with type="number" and type="email"

Comment: try to var_dump() your $_POST['phone'] and $_POST['email'] to see if you get something.

Comment: are you putting your php code in process.php , or another file ?

Comment: First thing I notice is the invalid HTML tag `lable`; it's `label`. This isn't the root of your problem though. You should turn on PHP logging and add this to the first line of your PHP code : `error_log("POST: " . print_r($_POST, true));` and see what's logged

Comment: php code goes in process.php

Comment: @parttimeturtle lable is changed to label. but that is just the html, and its got nothing to do with the php retrieval.

Comment: @KeerthiDsouza Which is why I ended that statement with "this isn't the root of your problem". What is the log output?

Comment: var_dump shows NULL on both

Comment: @parttimeturtle
[08-Oct-2019 16:48:25 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: phone in /home/xxx/public_html/xx/process.php on line 10
[08-Oct-2019 16:48:25 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /home/xxx/public_html/xx/process.php on line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you forgot to add "=" in your input tags

Change

```
<input name"phone" type="number">
<input name"email" type="email">
```

to

```
<input name="phone" type="number">
<input name="email" type="email">
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of: `echo "Your phone number is $phone and your email ID is $email";`
Try this: `echo "Your phone number is".$phone."and your email ID is".$email;`

Comment: The syntax giving by the OP is correct, since, in PHP, it could be successfully interpreted.

Comment: While variable expansion within double quotes should technically be surrounded in curly braces, this would have no effect on the code. Proof: the name 'Keerthi' is expanded just fine.

Comment: @SevnSune That dint work for me. I am still retrieving blank value.